# Automatically generate chronological entries

Tags: latex, chronological

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZvW1.png)

I want there is some commands in LaTeX or LaTeX packages that I can extract, group and sort text from my documents.

In the MWE above, I'd like to manually edit the section 1 and 2, while automatically generate the section 3 from section 2. I want some user defined command can to this:

1. extract all the dates and activities from section 2.
2. group all the activities by dates.
3. sort all the activities by dates.

Is it possible to accomplish that? Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I forgot edit the image description... It seems I don't have permissions to edit my post.

Comment: Please click "enter image description here" to see the picture.

Activities may not be the progress, it can be any text. Section 2 will be edit regularly, and 10+ activities may be add to that section each time.

It's too cumbersome to manually edit section 3 (extracting, grouping and sorting).